# Models not getting registered to admin in Django?

Tags: python, django

I was just starting to make a quiz app in django when i encountered this problem. The problem is that that my models are not getting registered in the admin page. I have tried a lot of methods but nothing seemed to work. Can someone help me with this?

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField()


class Questions(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.TextField()
    op1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    op2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    op3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    op4 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Quiz, Questions

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Quiz)
admin.site.register(Questions)
```

Comment: Have you added the app to INSTALLED_APPS in settings?

Comment: Have you run the migrations?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed app in you `setting.py` file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'Your_app_name',
    ...
]
```

Then run folowing two commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Then it should work perfectly.